# Find maximum and minimum of $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ subject to constraints $x+2y+z=8$ and $x-y=4$

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Find maximum and minimum of $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ subject to constraints $x+2y+z=8$ and $x-y=4$

My try:I solved it by Lagrange multiplier method  but I found one set of value as $x=52/11,y=8/11,z=20/11$ Then how can i find both maximum and minimum of $f$.

Comment: you can derive a function only in $x$

Comment: sorry sir...i did not get you.

Comment: Use the constraints to eliminate $y$ and $z$ and express $f$ as a function of $x$ alone.

Comment: that's exactly what i said above

Comment: I know. I just tried to express it slightly different because OP apparently did not yet understand it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $y=x-4$ and $z=8-2y-x=16-3x$. This gives (show it !):

$f(x,y,z)=11x^2-104x+272$

Comment: But this gives only the minimum value, sir.

Comment: this is not true, since we have no $$f(x,y,z)$$ please correct it

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner What is "not true" here, Graubner?

Answer (score 1):

from the first condition we obtain $$z=8-x-2y$$ and from the second one $$y=x-4$$ plugging this in our function $f(x,y,z)$ we get
$$h(x)=11\,{x}^{2}-104\,x+272$$

Comment: $y=4-x$ is wrong (and therefore also the expression for $h$).

Comment: it is just corrected Martin